# symfony5 - not working after composer udpate (cache issue)

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, composer-php

My website is down since `composer update`. The issue seems not on the updated packages themselves (I run them in dev environment without problems, too). It seems that 'only' the cache cannot clean itself correctly.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.1.*"

Prefetching 9 packages  
  - Downloading (100%)

Package operations: 0 installs, 51 updates, 3 removals
  - Removing symfony/uid (v5.1.8)
  - Removing symfony/polyfill-uuid (v1.20.0)
  - Removing easycorp/easyadmin-bundle (v3.1.9)
  - Updating symfony/flex (v1.10.0 => v1.11.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/routing (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/http-foundation (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/event-dispatcher (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/var-dumper (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/error-handler (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/http-kernel (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/finder (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/filesystem (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/dependency-injection (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/config (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/var-exporter (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/cache (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/framework-bundle (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/doctrine-bridge (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/string (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/console (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating doctrine/doctrine-bundle (2.2.1 => 2.2.2): Loading from cache
  - Updating doctrine/inflector (1.4.3 => 2.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Updating doctrine/common (3.0.2 => 3.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating doctrine/orm (2.7.4 => 2.8.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating laminas/laminas-code (3.5.0 => 3.5.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/asset (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/dotenv (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/property-info (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/property-access (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/options-resolver (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/intl (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/form (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/mime (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/mailer (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/security-core (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/security-http (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/security-guard (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/security-csrf (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/security-bundle (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/serializer (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/translation (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/validator (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/yaml (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating nikic/php-parser (v4.10.2 => v4.10.3): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/maker-bundle (v1.24.2 => v1.25.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/stopwatch (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating doctrine/migrations (2.3.0 => 2.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/http-client (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/twig-bridge (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/debug-bundle (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/monolog-bridge (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/twig-bundle (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/web-profiler-bundle (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/css-selector (v5.1.8 => v5.1.9): Loading from cache
Generating autoload files
composer/package-versions-deprecated: Generating version class...
composer/package-versions-deprecated: ...done generating version class
84 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

What about running composer global require symfony/thanks && composer thanks now?
This will spread some   by sending a ★  to the GitHub repositories of your fellow package maintainers.

Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!  
!!   // Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug                      
!!   // false                                                                       
!!  
!!  
!!  In ORMException.php line 40:
!!                                                                                 
!!    It's a requirement to specify a Metadata Driver and pass it to Doctrine\ORM  
!!    \Configuration::setMetadataDriverImpl().                                     
!!                                                                                 
!!  
!!  cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
!!  
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

It says something about `Doctrine\ORM\Configuration::setMetadataDriverImpl()` but I have never heard about this.

Any idea what I could do? Thanks!

---

### EDIT:

If I change in `.env.local` to `env=dev` it works. Also the cache-cleaning.
But If I try `./bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`, I get this error:

```
$ ./bin/console cache:clear --env=prod

In ORMException.php line 40:
                                                                               
  It's a requirement to specify a Metadata Driver and pass it to Doctrine\ORM  
  \Configuration::setMetadataDriverImpl().
```

---

### EDIT 2:

Maybe it is connected wit this:

**config/packages/prod/doctrine.yaml**

```yaml
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
        query_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
        result_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool
#...
```

Comment: Please share all error messages in readable form, that means: as text

Comment: Also, please share which packages were updated. Did you run `composer update` on a production system?

Comment: yes, I did run it on production system (text-form added to EDIT 3)

Comment: Please never do this. Change dependencies on your local system, put `composer.lock` under version control, run `composer install` during the deployment - but never run `composer update` on any other system, as you will lose the control over the package versions then

Comment: Also, please add **all** error messages in text form to your question

Comment: pics replaced by text. Anyway, I still have the issue. The cache is not clearing.

Comment: Then do the following as a quick step: revert the change and deploy the latest working version of your website. Afterwards, set your local development system to `APP_ENV=prod` and update one package after another (running `composer update packagename`) to check which one is responsible for the problem

Comment: rm -rf var/cache should do the trick i guess

Comment: @UrmatZhenaliev: You made my day! Thanks! Do you know why? It feels like a workaround. I guess I need to change somewhere something in the code to make it work in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When switching between environments I sometimes have to delete the cache folders manually.

When this happens, I usually do:

```
rm -rf var/cache/prod var/cache/dev
```